How to generalize the autogenerated Open-Meteo API call to arbitrary weather variables
I'm using the open-source weather API open-meteo to download weather data. The website provides autogenerated python API calls in the documentation section.
I would like to generalize this API call to be able to request arbitrary weather variables using the same code.
For a minimal working example, I will use the documentation page mentioned above and set the following values:
Location (somewhere in Hamburg):

Latitude: 53.33
Longitude: 9.99

Hourly Weather Variables, tick:

Temperature (2 m)
Wind Speed (10 m)

This generates the following API call for downloading the hourly values of the observables temperature_2m (air temperature 2m above the ground) and wind_speed_10m (wind speed 10m above the ground) at a location somewhere in Hamburg.
import openmeteo_requests

import requests_cache
import pandas as pd
from retry_requests import retry

# Setup the Open-Meteo API client with cache and retry on error
cache_session = requests_cache.CachedSession('.cache', expire_after = 3600)
retry_session = retry(cache_session, retries = 5, backoff_factor = 0.2)
openmeteo = openmeteo_requests.Client(session = retry_session)

# Make sure all required weather variables are listed here
# The order of variables in hourly or daily is important to assign them correctly below
url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast"
params = {
    "latitude": 53.55,
    "longitude": 9.99,
    "hourly": ["temperature_2m", "wind_speed_10m"]
}
responses = openmeteo.weather_api(url, params=params)

# Process first location. Add a for-loop for multiple locations or weather models
response = responses[0]
print(f"Coordinates {response.Latitude()}°N {response.Longitude()}°E")
print(f"Elevation {response.Elevation()} m asl")
print(f"Timezone {response.Timezone()} {response.TimezoneAbbreviation()}")
print(f"Timezone difference to GMT+0 {response.UtcOffsetSeconds()} s")

# Process hourly data. The order of variables needs to be the same as requested.
hourly = response.Hourly()
hourly_temperature_2m = hourly.Variables(0).ValuesAsNumpy()
hourly_wind_speed_10m = hourly.Variables(1).ValuesAsNumpy()

hourly_data = {"date": pd.date_range(
    start = pd.to_datetime(hourly.Time(), unit = "s", utc = True),
    end = pd.to_datetime(hourly.TimeEnd(), unit = "s", utc = True),
    freq = pd.Timedelta(seconds = hourly.Interval()),
    inclusive = "left"
)}
hourly_data["temperature_2m"] = hourly_temperature_2m
hourly_data["wind_speed_10m"] = hourly_wind_speed_10m

hourly_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = hourly_data)
print(hourly_dataframe)

My approach so far is to introduce a new python variable custom_variables_list for the names of the weather variables and then loop over it. I skip the part where the ValuesAsNumpy arrays are assigned to new variables only to be then copied to the dictionary. This looks as follows:

import openmeteo_requests

import requests_cache
import pandas as pd
from retry_requests import retry

custom_variables_list = ["temperature_2m", "wind_speed_10m"]

# Setup the Open-Meteo API client with cache and retry on error
cache_session = requests_cache.CachedSession('.cache', expire_after = 3600)
retry_session = retry(cache_session, retries = 5, backoff_factor = 0.2)
openmeteo = openmeteo_requests.Client(session = retry_session)

# Make sure all required weather variables are listed here
# The order of variables in hourly or daily is important to assign them correctly below
url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast"
params = {
    "latitude": 53.55,
    "longitude": 9.99,
    "hourly": custom_variables_list
}
responses = openmeteo.weather_api(url, params=params)

# Process first location. Add a for-loop for multiple locations or weather models
response = responses[0]
print(f"Coordinates {response.Latitude()}°N {response.Longitude()}°E")
print(f"Elevation {response.Elevation()} m asl")
print(f"Timezone {response.Timezone()} {response.TimezoneAbbreviation()}")
print(f"Timezone difference to GMT+0 {response.UtcOffsetSeconds()} s")

# Process hourly data. The order of variables needs to be the same as requested.
hourly = response.Hourly()
# hourly_temperature_2m = hourly.Variables(0).ValuesAsNumpy()  <--- Do not allocate new variables for each observable
# hourly_wind_speed_10m = hourly.Variables(1).ValuesAsNumpy()

hourly_data = {"date": pd.date_range(
    start = pd.to_datetime(hourly.Time(), unit = "s", utc = True),
    end = pd.to_datetime(hourly.TimeEnd(), unit = "s", utc = True),
    freq = pd.Timedelta(seconds = hourly.Interval()),
    inclusive = "left"
)}
for i, x in enumerate(custom_variables_list):  # loop over the list of custom variables
    hourly_data[x] = hourly.Variables(i).ValuesAsNumpy()  # <--- Assign the values here

hourly_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = hourly_data)
print(hourly_dataframe)

The code runs without errors and prints the dataframe content.
My Question: Is this a valid approach or am I missing some aspects leading to unexpected behavior?
In particular, I'm asking since I do not really understand the allocation of individual variables before assigning them to the dictionary in the original API call.
I thought about this and I do not see any reason to introduce the extra variables in the original autogenerated call.
